# Mapkit - Overzoomed custom tiles not rendering when Polygons are present

Tags: ios, mapkit, rendering, tiles, polygons

I'm providing an MKMapView with an MKTileOverlay that replaces the map content. The backing tile provider only goes up to zoom level 15. If the user zooms in beyond zoom level 15 it upscales the level 15 tiles on the map instead of going blank.

However, if there is an MKPolygon or MKPolyline present in the map sector, it will only display the shape. It will no longer render the backing tile under it. This only happens when you overzoom.

I've seen some discussiong about overzooming in MapKit but they all seem to be related to versions prior to iOS 7 when a large amount of the Maps appear to have been changed.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

I realized that I was completely misinterpreting the functionality that MapKit provides for Map Tiles.

When I zoomed in and saw that my Tiles were rendering I assumed it was an overzoom feature. When the areas that had Polygons were not rendering the Map Tiles as these zoom levels I thought the Polygon Renderer was somehow shutting off the tile Renderer. As it turns out, because the only active renderer at that zoomed in level was the Polygon renderer that was the only part of the canvas being redrawn, so the rest of the canvas was just still showing what it already had on there.

In laymans' terms:

The Map Tile Renderer tells the map "I can draw this large area at zoom levels 0-5." The Polygon Renderer tells the map "I can draw this small area at all zoom levels."

When I'm at zoom level 5 both the Map Tile Renderer and the Polygon Renderer kick off and draw the regions they can handle. When I move into zoom level 6 only the Polygon Renderer kicks off. The map says "I have a renderer that can draw in this region so I'm going to redraw it with that information." Because the Map Tile Renderer doesn't provide tiles for zoom level 6 it won't kick off. The rest of the map still has tiles because there is no renderer that can draw for it, so the map just keeps what it already has on the canvas.

tl;dr: I mistook MapKit not making superfluous draw calls as an overzooming feature.